# Last Value of a Column but When It Is a Column of Formulas

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have tried everything on the web.
I have a column of formulas that display either a number or `""`.
I want to get the last VALUE from this column range.

Column is B8:B108 and the cells contains a formula like:

```
=if((ROW(B9)-8) < $G$9, if((ROW(B9)-8) < ($G$9-$G$10), B8*(1+$C$3), B8*(1-$C$2)),"")
```

This will return a number or `""` to the cell.

Every example online I can find has a solution for when the cells are just number or empty, not when the cells contain formulas that compute numbers or `""`.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet pls with example of desired output

Answer (score 0):

instead your formula use this one:

```
=IF((ROW(B9)-8) < $G$9, IF((ROW(B9)-8) < ($G$9-$G$10), B8*(1+$C$3), B8*(1-$C$2)), )
```

and then to get the last non-empty value you can do simple:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(INDIRECT("B"&MAX(IF(B8:B108<>"", ROW(B8:B108), ))))
```

---

also instead your formulae per row you could just use ArrayFormula in row **8**:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((ROW(B9:B109)-8) < G9, 
              IF((ROW(B9:B109)-8) < G9-G10, B8:B108*(1+C3), B8:B108*(1-C2)), ))
```

Comment: wow. figured there would be a simpler way to do this, or even a built in function.